# Why can't connect to mysql?

Tags: php

#### This is my code working ok on local pc by Xampp:

```
$this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbdata', 'root','123456');
$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

#### phi.ini:

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_odbc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

But when I uploaded it to my server:  using **win server 2012**, **apache 2.4**, **php 7.1**,
the given error occurred:

> PDOException: PDO::__construct(): PHP was built without openssl extension, can't send password encrypted in
>
> C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWDB.php:41 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWDB.php(41):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '123456') #1
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\app\model\Home.php(21):
>   ACWDB->__construct() #2
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWController.php(164):
>   Home_model::action_index() #3
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWController.php(32):
>   ACWController->dispach() #4
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWCore.php(116):
>   ACWController->main(NULL) #5
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\index.php(44): ACWCore::acwork() #6 {main}
>   Next PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWDB.php:41 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWDB.php(41):
>   PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '123456') #1
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\app\model\Home.php(21):
>   ACWDB->__construct() #2
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWController.php(164):
>   Home_model::action_index() #3
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWController.php(32):
>   ACWController->dispach() #4
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\acwork\class\ACWCore.php(116):
>   ACWController->main(NULL) #5
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\simsodep\index.php(44): ACWCore::acwork() #6 {main}

### Why can't connect to mysql?

Comment: Your list of modules doesn't include `openssl`. You can check the compiled in modules with `php -m`

Comment: Please also attach php.ini

Comment: @Count : i updated my question

Comment: Can you connect to the database using other tools like mysql CLI client?

Comment: i try https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp, it can't connect Connection failed: MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like openssl is not enabled in your php.ini. First open php.ini file

If you are using linux, find **extension=php_openssl.so** and uncomment it.

for windows, find **extension=php_openssl.dll** and uncomment it.

Also make sure to add **use PDO;** on top of the file if you havent.

Good Luck!

Comment: same error?? @DT also, try rebooting apache after the update

Comment: vâng, tôi khởi động lại apache

Answer (score 1):

From MySQL doc :

If your MySQL installation must serve pre-8.0 clients and you encounter compatibility issues after upgrading to MySQL 8.0 or higher, the simplest way to address those issues and restore pre-8.0 compatibility is to reconfigure the server to revert to the previous default authentication plugin

Change the default authentication plugin setting in th my.cnf file and restart MySQL service.

[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password

Change also the account authentication plugin and password:

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

It works for me.